# Pseudo-columns for partitioning parquet

Tags: parquet, partitioning, pyarrow, apache-arrow

I have some raw data I've converted to parquet format and I'd like to partition these files based on year and month. The end goal is to eventually use pyarrow and libraries like duckdb to query this data on top of a data lake(S3), for this example local functionality is fine.

I don't want to perform any additional transformations to the raw data and I've read by using configurations we can provide pseudo-columns for our data that represents year and month, even though those columns don't exist in the file.

I experimented using a column in the file already called 'Month, but turns out it's not valid for all cases in the file and I don't want to write over it at this stage. There is a field called 'date' in string timestamp format "05/15/2023 15:01" and I'd like to explore how I could use that field to create the partition structure preferably with those pseudo-columns so I don't need to alter the raw data.

Each individual parquet file should in theory have the same month and year values with possible outliers.